# Disabling future date in daterange picker using moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have a daterange picker in my HTML file

```
<input date-range-picker class="form-control date-picker" type="text" 
ng-model="datePicker.date" options="onApplyDateRange"/>
```

I want to know that is it possible to validate it using moment.js .I have been trying to validate it but I'm not able to get it working. Please help

I have used https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-daterangepicker https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker

Comment: Did you try and set the `maxDate` property, e.g. `$scope.datePicker.date = {…, maxDate: moment()}`?

Answer (score 1):

you can try using max in the html and get the maxdate from controller

```
<input date-range-picker class="form-control date-picker" type="text" ng-model="datePicker.date" max="maxdate" options="onApplyDateRange"/>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.maxdate = new Date();
```