# Unable to set minDate and MaxDate in Angular js datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am very new to angular JS and I am trying to fix `minDate` and `maxDate` to from and to date pickers, I have tried th code below but it is not working:

```
<input type="text" name="mydate" id="sd" min-date="minDate" placeholder="Select a date" class="form-control datepicker" min-date="minDate" ng-model="enquiry.startdate" ng-blur="updateRate()" required>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
```

The following is my controller code:

```
function enquiryCtrl($scope,DataServices,$stateParams,SweetAlert,$state,DTOptionsBuilder,DTColumnDefBuilder){
    // some other code
    var date = new Date();
    $scope.minDate=date; //I am trying to set today date as minDate
}
```

but its not working it's taking past dates too

Following is edited code

```
function getMinDate()
{
    console.log("From Date---- "+$('#sd').text())
    return $('#sd').val();
}

$('#dd').daterangepicker({
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "dateLimit": {
        "days": 7
    },


    "minDate":getMinDate(),

},function(start, end, label) {
      console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});

$('#sd').daterangepicker({
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "dateLimit": {
        "days": 7
    },
    "startDate": new Date(),
    "endDate": new Date(),
    "minDate": new Date()
},function(start, end, label) {
      console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});
```

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker Please see this.

Comment: first for date there is a bower called angular datepicker [check this link it is same as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830712/disabling-future-date-in-daterange-picker-using-moment-js/45830830#45830830)

Comment: @Vignesh hi, But I need like this from and To date is there anyother way ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="demo">
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

> $(function() {
>       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
>           dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
>           changeYear: true,
>           changeYear: true,
>           minDate: new Date(),
>           maxDate: new Date(2017, 10-1, 30)
>       });
>   });

Comment: can we dynamically set the minDate and maxDate ?

Comment: Ya we can do that using date range picker only

Comment: can .I have any example ?

Comment: i have tried a fiddle that has three date ranges and is working fine have a look [js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vignesh230794/Lt7aP/5282/)